# Is there a way to hold to long jump in Unity with a touchInput button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm making a game and I want jumping to feel like jumping in Super Mario Bros. I'm able to get the result I want with a Keyboard or a Controller because they have KeyDown, Key (While pressed), and KeyUp. But touchButtons only have a single boolean. (Pressed or Not Pressed) Is there a way I can work around this?

I tried using Input.GetTouch and using the begin and end phase, this gave the correct result but I'm not sure how to implement it into a GUI button.

The code I'm using has a GUI button with a script that when the button is pressed, joybutton.Pressed = true

```
void PlayerJump()
{
    bool canJump = charController.isGrounded;

    //Button Pressed start jumpDuration
    if (joybutton.Pressed && canJump)
    {
        isJumping = true;
        jumpDuration = jumpTime;
    }


    if (isJumping == true)
    {
        if (jumpDuration > 0)
        {
            vertical_Velocity = jump_Force;
            jumpDuration -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

    //timer runs out
        else
        {
           isJumping = false;
        }
    }

    //cancel jump if mid-air
    if (!joybutton.Pressed)
    {
        isJumping = false;
    }
}
```

I have no way of stopping the player from jumping as soon as they land with the GUI touchButton. I get desired results with keyboard and gamepad buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable to remember the state of the button last frame. That way, you can enter the jump start block only if it's the first frame of the button being hit:

```
private bool wasJumpPressedLastFrame = false;

void PlayerJump()
{
    bool canJump = charController.isGrounded;

    //Button Pressed start jumpDuration
    if (joybutton.Pressed && canJump && !wasJumpPressedLastFrame )
    {
        isJumping = true;
        jumpDuration = jumpTime;
    }


    if (isJumping == true)
    {
        if (jumpDuration > 0)
        {
            vertical_Velocity = jump_Force;
            jumpDuration -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

    //timer runs out
        else
        {
           isJumping = false;
        }
    }

    //cancel jump if mid-air
    if (!joybutton.Pressed)
    {
        isJumping = false;
    }

    wasJumpPressedLastFrame = joyButton.Pressed;
}
```